# PHP: passing two variables from <SELECT> value to the controller via method= "post"

Tags: php, variables, controller

I have a select div in front end that looks like this:

[image]

The HTML code of that view is as follows:

```
<form action="StatisticsController@getTime" method="post">
    <select>
        <option value="all" selected>All dates</option>
            <?php foreach ($available_years_with_months as $the_year => $months): ?>
            <?php foreach ($months as $the_month): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $the_month; ?> <?php echo $the_year; ?>">
                    <?php echo $the_month; ?> <?php echo $the_year; ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

I am trying to pass two variables ($month and $ year) from that SELECT back to the controller.

My Controller looks like this:

```
    class StatisticsController extends Controller
      {
        ....
        public function getTime($the_month, $the_year) {
            some code
        }
        ....
      }
```

But I get the following error:

**ErrorException in StatisticsController.php line 132: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\StatisticsController::getTime()**

the line 132 is the following:

```
public function getTime($the_month, $the_year) {
```

It seems that the post method is not sending both variables.

The question is: **what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I would suggest to have an option value something like <option value="2017-02">2017 February</option> and then on server side you just split the actual value by "-"